# How to remove/correct log4j 1.x dependency from wildfly 8.2.1 module System

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, wildfly

How to remove/correct log4j 1.x dependency from wildfly 8.2.1 module System.
While scanning I have found log4j 1.x jar available at path wildfly-8.2.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\log4j\main\log4j-1.2.16.jar.
We have already upgraded over application code with log4j 2.x dependency .

Please advise.

Comment: There is no real reason to remove it and you likely cannot as other modules depend on it.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Business wants to remove/upgrade this jar with latest log4j 2.17.1 jar.

Comment: It cannot be done. There are modules that require log4j1.